# Why is my Ngrx action undefined when calling getReloadAction()?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

```
export class NgrxClass {
    

    public _reloadAction: Action;


    constructor(private _store: Store<VehicleState>) {
       
    }

    public load(vId?: number): void {
        this._reloadAction  = VehiclesLoadAction({ vId });
        this._store.dispatch(this._reloadAction);
    }

   
    public getReloadAction(): Action {
        return this._reloadAction ;
    }

  
}
```

I am saving `VehiclesLoadAction({ vId })` in `this._reloadAction` when I am calling the load Method but when the call the `getReloadAction()` I am getting this._reloadAction as ***`undefined`***.
I dont know if the class is getting re-initialised .

i am expecting `VehiclesLoadAction({ vId })` with the parameter when i call getReloadAction() menthod but its undefined

Answer (score 0):

if `this._reloadAction` is `undefined` it's probably because `VehiclesLoadAction` returns `undefined`.

Comment: But VehiclesLoadAction works fine in load method , but when returned getReloadAction it is getting reinitialised to undefiend

Comment: hard to say then without a reproduction, this snipped probably lack some code as well which makes it hard.